# Dynamic resizing height not working of bar chart as number of teams increasing in my case

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bar-chart, rally

Using Highcharts for displaying count of severities teamwise, but as number of teams increases the labels get collapses with each other, is there any soultion by with I can resize the chart height depending on the number of teams.
See the image for the reference, it get worse as number of teams increases.

[image]

Comment: Just call `chart.setSize(new_width, new_height)` to resize chart. Of course first calculate height according to number of categories.

Comment: @PawełFus Thanks...tried the same and its working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `chart.setSize(new_width, new_height)` to resize chart. Of course first calculate height according to number of categories.